# How can I Upgrade PowerShell from version 2.0 to 3.0 Windows Server 2008 R2 ( Without a Reboot )

Tags: powershell-3.0

I need a way to Upgrade PowerShell from version 2.0 to 3.0 including prerequisites for Windows Server 2008 R2 ( Without a Reboot ) how can I do this ?

Comment: Looks like this was covered over at Server Fault http://serverfault.com/questions/539229/possible-to-upgrade-powershell-2-0-to-3-0-without-a-reboot.

Comment: nope he just said it requires one no one is trying to figure out a way to pull it off without a reboot

Comment: This is off topic, sorry. You should try on superuser

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it, sadly.  PowerShell gets upgraded along with the Windows Management Framework which is a core service/element of Windows.  I've successfully got certain aspects of PowerShell to work when upgrading the WMF before rebooting, but it is very erratic.

Moral of the story: No, you can't do it.